# Run go with VSCODE is not working

Tags: macos, go, visual-studio-code

i've installed the latest go (I saw the go outout with go -v in the command line )

I've installed go plugins to vs code and restart and create some simple file like following

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("hello world");
}
```

when I run it (with run option plugin , click on file and run)  I got  error in the console

```
[Running] go run "/Users/i076777/GoProjects/GoProjTest/main.go"
/bin/sh: go: command not found
```

Any idea what Im missing here ?

I've also try the following which doesnt work
 Ive MAC and I see in env `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"` and I use `'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/'` and its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing go in your path it looks like. Check with echo $PATH and you should have `:/c/Go/bin:` in it somewhere (or the folder you installed go to).

As a side test, open a command prompt / shell and type `go env` - if it is in your path you should get your go environment variables showing - if they do appear, please update the question.

Comment: Thanks I know that but here its a bit difficult... , i've mac and I see in env `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"` and I use  'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/' and its not working...

Comment: If it was not in the path and you exported it, the export is only for that shell, open a new shell and check your path again.

Comment: Ok but Im trying to run simple program, this path after I export should work, isnt it ? any other idea ?

Comment: I close the ITerm command line and it doesnt help ,After I close and open VS code it's working ...thanks

Comment: I don't understand why people down vote this question since I think its relevant to others too , this is bug in VSCode I guess...

Comment: Sightly odd behaviour of VSCode, but glad its working